# HQL query - cutting string

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

Can anyone tell me - is it possible to do something like this in HQL query:

I've got a string like "xxxxxx/yyyy" and I need to separate parts from this string. I mean use string part "xxxxxx" as one pattern and use "yyyy" as the second pattern in where clause. Is it possible? I couldn't fin answer for it in google. The amount of characters in "xxxxxx" part and "yyyy" part is unknown so i need to separate it by finding character "/".

Thank in advance!

Comment: Can you improve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Split to split the string into a string array. Beware that it will blow up if the delimiter is missing from the string.

```
var myArray = "xxxxxx/yyyy".Split('/');
var left = myArray[0];
var right = myArray[1];
```

Then you can use left and right in the where clause.